# Parent attributes not working in Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

Not sure if this is default behavior but I'm trying to build a component in Vue and trying to add attributes like id & class but is not present in the rendered code.

Component

```html
<template>
    <input type="text" name="hello" />
</template>
```

Usage (named md-input)

```html
<md-input class="hello" />

<!-- this will render too wihtout the class attr -->
<input type="text" name="hello" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, attributes are passed onto the root element of the component, as seen in this
[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-inherited-class-binding-in-vue-3-hzdpf?file=/src/App.vue).

But that can't happen when there are multiple elements in the component, and you'd see a warning in the browser's console:

```
[Vue warn]: Extraneous non-props attributes (class) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. 
  at <MdInput class="hello" > 
  at <App>
```

For that scenario, you could pass on any attribute bindings to the inner `input` using [`v-bind="$attrs"`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-bind):

```html
<template>
  <label for="hello">My Input</label>
  <input type="text" name="hello" v-bind="$attrs" />
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-inherited-class-binding-in-vue-3-forked-sxogd?file=/src/components/MdInput.vue:83-98)

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird behavior, what if you put a default class on the component's template?

```
<template>
    <input type="text" name="hello" class="default" />
</template>


<md-input class="hello" />

<!-- The element should be render like this --> 
<input type="text" name="default hello" />
```